# Can't login into magento backend. Its redirecting to same page

Tags: magento2.4.3, xampp

I have installed the magento2.4.3 version using xampp server and configured everything.
But I try to login to the Magento admin its always returns on the same page. I have tried the all solution from google search.

I have debugged the Magento core code. In signin Controller, they are checking whether the user is logged in or not. so they get the user info from authsession. It always returns null values.

Did anyone face the same issue? Please suggest me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Run Below Command In SSH :
`bin/magento config:set system/security/max_session_size_admin 2560000`

Comment: I have tried it. but still not working

Answer (score 0):

This should be happened due to cache issue. You can try this on private window.
If you are still getting the issue then web/secure/use_in_adminhtml was set to 0 by using the following command:

```
php bin/magento config:show web/secure/use_in_adminhtml
```

However, after changing it to 1, the redirect error was still present.  I then removed the contents of the var/cache folder.

I was then able to connect to the admin login page and login.

Comment: I have tried it. but still not working